# IIS 7 Custom Session Provider In Root Web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I am trying to setup a custom session provider in my default / root web.config so that all of it's child sites are able to use it automatically.

Here's my configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionStateProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="RedisSessionStateProvider" 
                    type="Harbour.RedisSessionStateStore.RedisSessionStateStoreProvider" 
                    host="xxx.yyy.zzz" clientType="pooled" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My issue is that the provider is dependent on a few assemblies, and I'm not sure of the proper  way to reference them in my root web.config such that the child sites can use it.

I'd like to avoid using the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put the assembly in the bin folder of the root website and then reference it in the web.config then use the add assembly tag.

See: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/200904/add-assembly-to-root-web.config-in-asp.net